# Removing box around text from google doc comments

Tags: ms-word, google-docs

I had a doc shared with my collaborators. So I commented my part on the google doc sheet itself. Later when I downloaded the same on Microsoft word I can see all the comments etc on the doc. I can also accept it, but the box/border remains around the text still remains. Even I try to click the No markup option the box still remains there. How do I can remove it

[image: figure]

Comment: Which box/border are you referring to?

Comment: Assuming you're referring to the box with a small grey tab on the upper left side, that's a Content Control. Right-click on it and choose Remove Content Control. In the future, please post this kind of question on http://answers.microsoft.com or Super User. Stack Overflow is for questions about programming, not how to use software.